# Why can't my app access by blob storage using this SAS token?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

I am attempting to access a blob storage account and simply list the contents of a container using a SAS token. I am generating an access policy (according to this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/manage-stored-access-policies-for-storage-accounts-from-within-the-azure-portal/)) and referencing that access policy within my access token as well.

Unfortunately, when my code attempts to run the `ListBlobsSegmented` function, I receive a 403 (Forbidden) error.

This is the code that attempts to get the listing of blobs:

```
string storageAccountName = "ringclone";
string containerName = "ringcentral-archives";
string authenticationKey = "?sv=2018-03-28&si=ringclone-access-policy&sr=c&sig=************************";
StorageCredentials creds;
CloudStorageAccount account;
CloudBlobClient blobClient;
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer;
creds = new StorageCredentials(authenticationKey);
account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, storageAccountName, endpointSuffix: null, useHttps: true);
blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
var containerSegment = blobClient.ListBlobsSegmented("", blobContinuationToken); // 403 error;
```

And these are the steps I am using to generate an access policy and generate a SAS token that references that access policy:

1. In the Azure Storage Explorer, I browse to blob storage and find the specific container I want to grant access to. I right-click and select "Manage Access Policies".

[image: Manage Access Policy]

2. I then provide all permissions to this policy, and provide an end date that is 20 years from now.

[image]

3. After clicking "Save", I go back to my container list and right-click on that container once more and select "Get Shared Access Signature".

[image]

4. Within the Shared Access Signature Dialog, I reference my access policy.

[image]

5. Upon clicking "Create", I have my Shared Access Signature with an attached policy.

[image]

6. I then simply copy/paste my storage account name, container name, and auth key into the code shown above. For the auth key, I use the "Query String" field shown in my SAS Signature dialog. For example:

**Query String field is used as auth key, according to the docs**

```
string storageAccountName = "ringclone";
string containerName = "ringcentral-archives";
string authenticationKey = "?sv=2018-03-28&si=ringclone-access-policy&sr=c&sig=************************"; // retrieved from the "Query String" field in storage explorer.
```

However, I am getting a 403 error when trying to list the blobs in my container. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below in a console app:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;

namespace AzureStorageTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string storageAccountName = "<storage account name>";
            string containerName = "<container name>";
            string sasToken = "<sas token>";
            StorageCredentials creds;
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer;
            creds = new StorageCredentials(sasToken);

            cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri("https://"+ storageAccountName + ".blob.core.windows.net/"+ containerName), creds);
            BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
            var blobs = cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmented("", blobContinuationToken);
            foreach (var blob in blobs.Results) {
                Console.WriteLine(blob.Uri);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: StorageCredentials and CloudBlobContainer belong to the old "WindowsAzure.Storage" namespace which is [deprecated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/). Maybe is better to use something like: https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/uploading-files-to-azure-blob-storage-with-shared-access-signature-sas