# How to use SAS Token to connect to Azure BlobStorage from C#?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

**tl;dr:** I'm trying to connect to an Azure BlobStorage from C# using a SAS, but cannot seem to get past a `StorageException` saying the "Server failed to authenticate the request." I suspect something is wrong with my connection string.

---

I am using libraries [`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) 11.2.3.0 and [`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/) 11.2.3.0 to connect to an Azure BlobStorage from a .NET Core 3.1 application.

My C# code to establish this connection starts as follows:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

When using a connection string that includes the fields `AccountName`, `AccountKey`, `EndpointSuffix`, and `DefaultEndpointsProtocol` (this is `https`)<sup>1</sup>, this works flawlessly. (I can connect and do things like enumerate containers and blobs, and also create containers and blobs and upload data.)

---

Now, I'm supposed to connect to that same BlobStorage with a SAS. For that purpose, I have been given the following bits of information (here anonymized to some kind of "placeholders" because I am going to refer to them in the following):

- `<StorageAccount>` (same as the value for the `AccountName` field in the aforementioned connection string)
- `<Container>`
- `<Blob-SAS-Token>`
- `<Blob-SAS-URL>` (this is actually composed of the other info found here, i.e. `<DefaultEndpointsProtocol>://<StorageAccount>.blob.<EndpointSuffix>/<Container>?<Blob-SAS-Token>`)

I can successfully establish a connection to said BlobStorage container from *Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer* by using the `<Blob-SAS-URL>` as described above.<sup>2</sup>

**However, I have so far been unable to successfully use the SAS from my C# code.**

I have tried various ways to write my connection string, such as:

- `BlobEndpoint=<DefaultEndpointsProtocol>://<StorageAccount>.blob.<EndpointSuffix>;SharedAccessSignature=<Blob-SAS-Token>`
- `BlobEndpoint=<DefaultEndpointsProtocol>://<StorageAccount>.blob.<EndpointSuffix>/<Container>;SharedAccessSignature=<Blob-SAS-Token>`

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-using-a-shared-access-signature), this *should* work. In there, a SAS-based connection string is outlined to contain up to five fields - `BlobEndpoint`, `QueueEndpoint`, `TableEndpoint`, `FileEndpoint`, and `SharedAccessSignature` - where only (any) one of the four endpoints *must* be specified beside the SAS.

I have also tried creating/populating the `CloudStorageAccount` instance differently than by means of a (possibly misformatted) connection string, such as:

```
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
    new StorageCredentials("<Blob-SAS-Token>"),
    "<StorageAccount>", "<EndpointSuffix>", true);
```

Unfortunately, no matter what I try, as soon as I attempt to retrieve any data from the BlobStorage this way, a `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException` is thrown, stating

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

UTC time on my local machine exactly matches current UTC time I can find on online sources. As I can connect with my SAS information from another application on the very same machine, the issue is most probably not related to any aspect of the environment (such as a missing entry for my IP address in some blocking list or similar), anyway. Rather than that, I suspect I am not providing an adequate set of information out of what I have been given for establishing the connection.

**What do I have to change to make this connection work?**

---

<sup>1</sup>: I am going to write this post with some sort of "placeholders" for the various identifiers and credentials so as to not divulge any confidential information. I hope this is not too confusing. On the other hand, it should actually allow for easily adapting the information to whichever sample endpoint is available by a couple of find-and-replace operations.

<sup>2</sup>: To do so, I right-click the *Storage Accounts* tree node, then *Connect to Azure Storage...* > *Blob Container* > *SAS URL (Shared Access Signature*

Comment: here is a similar issue you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70097124/how-to-connect-to-blob-storage-container-using-c-sharp/70101018?noredirect=1#comment123928413_70101018

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT: That was indeed helpful, thank you. Can you add an answer? For me, the crucial point here was that when using a (container-specific) SAS, I cannot just use the same code for connecting to the BlobStorage as I would with a connection string for the entire storage account. That is, there is no way to put the SAS and target container into a connection string and feed it to `CloudStorageAccount.Parse` (or is there?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Connection string-based solution below.**

Based on [Swetha's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70102856/how-to-use-sas-token-to-connect-to-azure-blobstorage-from-c#comment123931137_70102856), I was able to connect using the following code:

```
var creds = new StorageCredentials("<Blob-SAS-Token>");
var blobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri("<DefaultEndpointsProtocol>://<StorageAccount>.blob.<EndpointSuffix>/<Container>"), creds);
```

I can then retrieve and upload data from/to `blobContainer`.

<s>Unfortunately, this means the code for connecting to the BlobStorage looks differently than with a connection string. Therefore, I will need to provide, test, and maintain two different code paths, depending on which kind of connection configuration has been supplied (and there is no guarantee a third authentication method will not require yet another code path - something I have now [asked about in a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70111820)).</s>

---

**UPDATE:** Based upon [an answer to my question about storing connection data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120872/5206621), I have now learned that it *is* actually possible to connect with a SAS using a connection string. The following formats have proven valid:

- `BlobEndpoint=<DefaultEndpointsProtocol>://<StorageAccount>.blob.<EndpointSuffix>;SharedAccessSignature=<Blob-SAS-Token>`
- `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=<DefaultEndpointsProtocol>;EndpointsSuffix=<EndpointsSuffix>;SharedAccessSignature=<Blob-SAS-Token>`

Then, an important point is that (at least if the SAS is container-specific like the one I got - I'm not sure this is always the case) I can work *in* the container, but not *on* the container (or anything outside of it). That is:

- While I can retrieve a `CloudBlobContainer` instance by passing the container name to `GetContainerReference`, I cannot call `ListContainers` (this throws an exception rather than enumerating just the set of containers that I can access with the SAS).
- I must assume the container is already existing. Both `Exists()` and `CreateIfNotExists()` will throw exceptions when called on the container.<sup>1</sup>

Once sticking to these restrictions, it is possible to use `CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString)` again.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I have created a [separate question about how to safely check for a container's existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121964).