# How does Azure BlobStorage connection data have to be stored to support all available addressing modes?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage, connection-string, credentials

I am using libraries [`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) 11.2.3.0 and [`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/) 11.2.3.0 to connect to an Azure BlobStorage from a .NET Core 3.1 application.

Users of my application are supposed to supply connection information to an Azure BlobStorage to/from where the application will deposit/retrieve data.

Initially, I had assumed allowing users to specify a *connection string* and a custom blob container name (as an optional override of the default) would be sufficient. I could simply stuff that connection string into the `CloudStorageAccount.Parse` method and get back a storage account instance to call `CreateBlobCloudClient` on.

---

Now that I'm trying to use this method to connect using a container-specific SAS (also see [my other question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70102856/how-to-use-sas-token-to-connect-to-azure-blobstorage-from-c)), it appears that the connection string might not be the most universal way to go.

Instead, it now seems a blob container URL, plus a SAS token *or* an account key (and possibly an account name, thought that seems to be included in the blob container URL already) are more versatile. However, I am concerned that the next way of pointing to a blob storage that I need to support (whichever that may be) might require yet another kind of information - hence my question:

**What set of "fields" do I need to support in the configuration files of my application to make sure my users can point to their BlobStorage whichever way they want, as long as they *have* a BlobStorage?**

(Is there maybe even a standard solution or best practice recommendation by Microsoft?)

---

*Please note that I am exclusively concerned with **what** to store. An arbitrarily long string? A complex object of sorts? If so, with what fields?*

*I am not asking **how** to store that configuration once I know what it must comprise. For example, this is not about securely encrypting credentials etc.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Workaround To access the Storage account using the SAS Token you need to pass the **Account Name along with the SAS Token and Blob Name** if you trying to upload and You need give the permission for your SAS Token .

**Microsoft recommends using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to authorize requests against blob and queue data if possible, instead of Shared Key. Azure AD provides superior security and ease of use over Shared Key. For more information about authorizing access to data with Azure AD, [see Authorize access to Azure blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory).**

**Note: Based on my testes you need to pass the Storage Account Name  And SAS Token and the Container Name And Blob name**

**Example:** I tried with uploading file to container using container level SAS Token . able to upload the file successfully.

[image]

```
const string sasToken = "SAS Token";
            StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(sasToken);

            const string accountName = "teststorage65";//Account Name
            const string blobContainerName = "test";
            const string blobName = "test.txt";
            const string myFileLocation = @"Local Path ";

            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, accountName, null, true);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
            //blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            cloudBlob.UploadFromFile(myFileLocation);
```

As you already know You can use the **Storage connection string** to connect with Storage.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Connection string");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
```

Your application needs to access the connection string at runtime to authorize requests made to Azure Storage.

You have several options for storing your connection string Or SAS Token

**1)** You can store your connection string in an environment variable.

**2)** An application running on the desktop or on a device can store the connection string in an **app.config** or **web.config** file. Add the connection string to the **AppSettings** section in these files.

**3)** An application running in an Azure cloud service can store the connection string in the **Azure service configuration schema (.cscfg) file**. Add the connection string to the ConfigurationSettings section of the service configuration file.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string

Comment: Thank you - so, using a connection string *is* possible after all. I think my issue was that I was trying to enumerate the containers using `ListContainers()`. My expectation was that the BlobStorage would return a filtered list of containers based on what my SAS can access; instead, it would throw an exception. If I use `GetContainerReference` to directly access a specific container instead, it works.