# How to programmatically find out what operations I can do in a blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

I am using libraries [`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) 11.2.3.0 and [`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/) 11.2.3.0 to connect to an Azure BlobStorage from a .NET Core 3.1 application.

When I started working on this, I had been given connection strings that gave me full access to the BlobStorage (or rather, the entire cloud storage account). Based upon those, I chose to write my connection code "defensively", making use of [`Exists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.exists?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) and [`CreateIfNotExists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.createifnotexists?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) from the [`CloudBlobContainer` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) to ensure the application would not fail when a container was not yet existing.

---

**Now, I'm connecting a BlobStorage container using a SAS.** While I can freely retrieve and upload blobs within the container like this, unfortunately, it seems that I am not allowed to do *anything* on the container level. Not only `CreateIfNotExists`, but even the mere querying of existence by `Exists()` throws a [`StorageException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.storageexception?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) saying

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

The documentation does not mention the exception.

**Is there any way to check preemptively whether I am *allowed* to check the container's existence?**

I have tried looking into the container permissions retrieved from [`GetPermissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getpermissions?view=azure-dotnet-legacy), but that will throw an exception, as well.

The only other alternative I can see is to check for container existence within a `try`-`catch`-block and assume existence if an exception is thrown ...

Comment: Does your SAS token include `sp` (signed permissions) attribute or is your SAS token created from an access policy (in that case your SAS token will include `si` attribute)?

Comment: @GauravMantri: It contains the `sp` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Added an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a no definitive way to identify if an operation can be performed using a SAS token other than performing that operation and catching any exception that may be thrown by the operation. The exception that is of your interest is `Unauthorized (403)`.

However you can try to predict if an operation can be performed by looking at the SAS token. If it is a [`Service SAS Token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) and not an [`Account SAS Token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas), that means all the account related operations are not not allowed. The way to distinguish between an Account SAS token and a Service SAS token is that the former will contain attributes like `SignedServices (ss)` and `SignedResourceTypes (srt)`.

Next thing you would want to do is look for `SignedPermissions (sp)` attribute in your SAS token. This attribute will tell you what all operations are possible with the SAS token. For example, if your SAS token is a Service SAS token and if it includes `Delete (d)` permission, that would mean you can use this SAS token to delete a blob.

Please see these tables for the permissions/allowed operations combinations:

- Service SAS Token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-directory-container-or-blob
- Account SAS Token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#permissions-for-a-directory-container-or-blob

Please note that the operation might still fail for any number of reasons like SAS token has expired, account key has changed since the generation of SAS token, IP restrictions etc.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. "SAS token has expired, account key has changed since the generation of SAS token, IP restrictions" - these should all be fine; if they apply, they will also prevent the execution of any of the crucial operations I perform on the blobs rather than just the existence checks I add for increased robustness.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in in my system to check whether the container exist or not able check it and if container not exists  created container and able to upload file.

You need to **give proper permission for your SAS Token**

[image]

```
const string sasToken = “SAS Token”

            const string accountName = "teststorage65";
            const string blobContainerName = "example";
            const string blobName = "test.txt";
            const string myFileLocation = @"Local Path ";

            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, accountName, null, true);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
            var result=blobContainer.Exists();
            if (result == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Container exists");
            }
            else
            {
               // blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
                Console.WriteLine("Conatiner not exists");

               Console.WriteLine("Creating Container   "+ blobContainerName);
                blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            }

               // blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
            //Console.WriteLine("Creating Container   ");
            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
            cloudBlob.UploadFromFile(myFileLocation);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[image]

Comment: "You need to give proper permission for your SAS Token" - I am not in control of the SAS token, so nothing can be changed about that.

Comment: ya ,You need to give the permission to your SAS Token,  How you getting the SAS Token?

Comment: Currently, the SAS token is supplied by the technical architect to whom I deliver my code. In production use, it will be provided by customers. Do note that **all the required business functionality works** with the current SAS token. Therefore, I have no real basis to argue for adding any permissions to the SAS token. Currently, my goal is to make the code more robust (by doing some container/blob existence checks), but only in cases where this does not conflict with the restrictions my connection is subject to.

Comment: Can you please check  with the Your technical architect , What are the allowed permission given for SAS Token ,See in Above answer I checked the existence of container using SAS token and able create it by giving permission as showed in above screenshot

Comment: While I think my particular problem will be solved by [Gaurav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70123348/5206621), I am still going to find out about this; this may well be of use to future visitors and to get a more complete picture.

Comment: I have had an opportunity to check the settings in the meantime, and one notable difference to your screenshot is that the three checkmarks on *Allowed Object Type* (*Service*, *Container*, and *Object*) are *not* set. Curious. So, this setting allows me to work within a blob container (and thereby deduce that it does exist), but bars me from explicitly asking whether it does indeed exist.